# hddtemp alias argument for all hard drives?

Tags: linux, zsh, alias

I currently have an alias in my .zshrc that looks somthing like this:

```
#hddtemp
alias hddtemp="hddtemp /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh 
/dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk /dev/sdl /dev/sdm /dev/sdn /dev/sdo /dev/sdp /dev/sdq /dev/sdr /dev/sds 
/dev/sdt /dev/sdu /dev/sdv /dev/sdw /dev/sdx /dev/sdy /dev/sdz /dev/sdaa /dev/sdab /dev/sdac 
/dev/sdad /dev/sdae /dev/sdaf /dev/sdag /dev/sdah /dev/sdai /dev/sdaj | sort -rnk4"
```

There HAS to be a better argument to get all of the hard drives that are plugged into my system...i'm just not sure how to express it.  Can someone help me out?  I'm sure awk has a way...

Comment: `zsh` is not `bash`

Comment: @Jetchisel -- what do you mean by this?  I've always been able to create aliases within zshrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lsblk` command to list the path of all disk block devices, `xargs` to turn the list into arguments for `hddtemp`:

```sh
alias allhddtemp="lsblk --include 8 --raw --output path --nodeps --nohead |
  xargs hddtemp |
  sort -rnk4"
```

Or better than `alias` make it a function and declare it inside `.zshenv`:

```sh
allhddtemp ()       
{
    lsblk --include 8 --raw --output path --nodeps --nohead |
       xargs hddtemp | sort -rnk4
}
```

Comment: I've never seen that "function" declaration before.  Good to know!

Only thing I'm having a problem with is sorting by the temperature since I have many different drives they are listed differently within "hddtemp".

     `/dev/sds: WDC WD80EDAZ-11TA3A0: 60°C`
and 
     `/dev/sdam: MD4000GBDS: 56°C`  are not in the appropriate order

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is better, but there is *shorter* argument to do this

```
alias hddtemps='hddtemp $(ls /dev/sd*)' #notice single quotes
```

kinda works in `bash`, in `zsh` it returns only one device, but that may be due to how wildcard works in `zsh`. I'm not too knowledgeable in `zsh`.

Comment: remove `ls`... just `hddtemp /dev/sd*`

Comment: @KamilCuk `sudo hddtemp /dev/sd*[^[:digit:]] | sort -k3rn`